# Force Spring to create a new singleton bean to replace corrupt one

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap

My application has a bean that occasionally gets corrupted and since it's a singleton I have to have the entire application restarted to get it refreshed.  Is it possible to have Spring destroy and recreate a singleton bean and replace all the references in existing beans?

If it matters, this is the bean that is giving me trouble.  Its an LdapContextSource connecting to our Active Directory.  Occasionally binding will stop working ("org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed") and then that's all she wrote until I can get the application bounced.

```
<bean id="adContextSourceTarget" 
    class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" ref="adUrl" />
    <property name="base" ref="adBase" />
    <property name="userDn" ref="adUsername" />
    <property name="password" ref="adPassword" />
</bean>
```

This application is running on two servers and they won't both be down at the same time so it's not that AD is down, it appears that if one of the servers happens to try to bind and there's a "hiccup" the bean cannot recover.  And therein lies my question, is there a way to force Spring to replace the existing Singleton bean with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend pooling the LDAP context source.  If the bind fails, close the connection and check another one out of the pool:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.1/reference/

Comment: How exactly do you "close the connection and check another one out of the pool" using ldapTemplate?

Comment: Did you look at section 5.1.3 Pooling in the link I sent you?